# How to create a tweet hierarchy tree structure in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm, neo4j-apoc

1.I was trying to build the relationships between each tweet nodes. A tweet can have multiple reply tweets and retweet tweets. Assuming I have two nodes which name Tweet and Tweets respectively. If Tweet.id = Tweets.reply_toid the relationship can be (Tweets)-[:replyto]->[Tweet]. If Tweet.id = Tweets.retweet_id the relationship can be (Tweets)-[:retweet]->[Tweet]. How can I create a tree structure like the screenshot below?
[image]

2 For example, A tweet ID is 123 , reply_to is 321, another tweet ID is 321 and the reply_to id is 456. Then the graph should be like 123-[reply]->321-[reply]->456. But for my result , I got separate reply_to results:  123-[reply]->321 321-[reply]->456. How can I create a hierarchy tree just like the screenshot photo?

```
CALL apoc.load.json("file:///tweets.json")
YIELD value
MERGE (t:Tweet {id: value.id})
WITH t, value
where exists(value.retweet_id) 
MERGE (c:Tweet {id: value.retweet_id})
MERGE (t)-[:retweet]->(c)
WITH t, value
where exists(value.replyto_id) 
MERGE (T:Tweet {id: value.replyto_id})
MERGE (t)-[:reply]->(T);
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, when you say you're trying to create a hierarchy tree. Are you referring to a specific visualization (maybe in the Neo4j browser)? Have you confirmed that your nodes are stored with proper relationships between each other? It's unclear what the specific issue is (is it a modeling issue? a visualization tool?). Also, it's unclear what you've done so far, and where you're stuck. The only thing you've shared is a drawing.

Comment: Sorry about that, I do not know how to describe this question clearly... I just wrote pice of code, could u please help me to check it?

Comment: Can you post a pic of how the data looks after you insert it using your code. Then it will be clear